# How to fix limits after multiple use of ax.voxels method in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxel

I'm doing a research with 3D point clouds that I receive from Lidar. I split huge amount of points (up to 10 - 100 millions) into cubes, investigate their position and display results in a seperate voxels using `Axes3D.voxels` method. However, I face some problems while setting appropriate limits of `Axes3D` after multiple use of this method.

I define `add_voxels` function in order to display voxels immediately from `np.array` of positions of cubes inputted:

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import itertools

def add_voxels(true_ids, ax):
    shape_of_filled = true_ids.max(axis=0) + 1  # shape of building
    filled = np.zeros(shape_of_filled)
    for n in true_ids:
        filled[n] = 1
    x, y, z = np.indices(np.array(shape_of_filled) + 1)
    return ax.voxels(x,y,z, filled)```

Then use it to plot my two clouds of cubes:

fig = plt.gcf()  # get a reference to the current figure instance
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')  # get a reference to the current axes instance
cubecloud1 = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(2,4), range(2,4), range(2,4))))
cubecloud2 = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(4,7), range(4,7), range(4,7))))
add_voxels(cubecloud2, ax)
add_voxels(cubecloud1, ax)
plt.show()
````

It results in bad limits of display of voxel's position:

[image]

I'd like to have all the components displayed in a correct bounding box like this:

[image]

Or, at least, this (assuming bounding box includes invisible voxels too):

[image]

Comment: What are the shapes of `cube1` and `cube2`? And what are `cubecloud1` and `cubecloud2` use for?

Comment: Sorry, it's typo. They are actually the same. I've fixed it.

Comment: cubecloud1 and cubecloud2 are two series of voxels that I use in my display.

Comment: For 3D axes you need to set the limits yourself in many cases. `ax.set_xlim(x0,x1)` etc.

Comment: Yes, I use these but I also expect to automate this process. One of possible uses can be interactive complement of display by a new voxel after each click.

Comment: I've also tested ```Axes3D.scatter``` and ```Axes3D.plot``` methods for adding 3D points and lines and they work well. If there's no better solution, I prefer inserting invisible points located on the sides of voxels in order to have limits of bounding box extended after each use of ```Axes3D.voxel``` command.

Comment: This is quite possibly a bug I made when I added the `voxels` method - it may be worth reporting upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only make this work by setting the axis limits explicitly:

```
# [...]
faces2 = add_voxels(cubecloud2, ax)
faces1 = add_voxels(cubecloud1, ax)
points = list(faces1.keys()) + list(faces2.keys())
data = list(zip(*points))
xmin = min(data[0])
xmax = max(data[0])
ymin = min(data[1])
ymax = max(data[1])
zmin = min(data[2])
zmax = max(data[2])
ax.set_xlim3d(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim3d(ymin, ymax)
ax.set_zlim3d(zmin, zmax)
plt.show()
```